# SQL Join Two Columns In Same Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to get records that are not used. My tables go like this:

**segment table**

```
| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | AAA  |
| 2  | BBB  |
| 3  | CCC  |
| 4  | DDD  |
```

**segment_segment_assoc**

```
| id | segment_name | child_name |
----------------------------------
| 1  | AAA          | BBB        |
| 2  | AAA          | CCC        |
```

The **segment_segment_assoc** table stores the parent/child relationships between the segments. I need a query that will be able to a **count** of how many segments in the **segment** table are **not** in the the **segment_segment_assoc** table.

The way I **want** to do this is somehow get the **segment_segment_assoc** table to transform to a single name type table. In example, it should turn to this =>

```
| name |
--------
| AAA  |
| BBB  |
| CCC  |
```

Where the **segment_segment_assoc.segment_name** and **segment_segment_assoc.child_name** columns are "appended" or "joined" together. Once I have that, I could then do a "NOT IN" to see which segments are not being "used" in the **segment_segment_assoc** table.

This should be written in SQL but just for context, I am using Postgres.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: this is just a simple union http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html ... `select segment_name from association union select child_name from association`

Comment: Removed the edits. Question is now back to the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using UNION should do the trick:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM segment
WHERE name NOT IN
(
    SELECT segment_name FROM segment_segment_assoc
    UNION
    SELECT child_name FROM segment_segment_assoc
)
```